# View photo album without having to scroll down for each picture

Tags: images

I need a way to see my photo albums without having to scroll down for each picture.
So, is there a way to lose the Header when I open the photo album ?
Or, can the photo album open in a new window ?
Thanks, Mike

Comment: would a slideshow be a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you are using to display that photo album (a plugin , custom post type, built-in gallery).
But if you want to remove the or display parts of your theme conditionally you can use the [**conditional tags**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) for example:

if your photo album is on a page with id 23 then you can add a condition in your theme's header.php to only display the header if it's not that page

```
<?php if (!is_page('23')){
         // the header stuff goes here
}?>
```